# How to set Lynx like motions in mc globally

Tags: linux, midnight-commander

I love the feature Lynx like motion in Midnight commander. Whenever I access new system, this is the first thing I customize. Now I am on a server with lots of system accounts and it becomes annoying. I am seeking for a way to apply it to all users.

This is `navigate_with_arrows=true` option in `~/.config/mc/ini`. This file is created on the first run, so I cannot run some script. There are lots of configuration at `/usr/share/mc` - except the ini file. The same applies to `/etc/mc`. Is there anything else how can I set it?

Comment: Can't you simply run `printf '%s\n' '[Panels]' 'navigate_with_arrows=true' > ~/.config/mc/ini`? It's a long command, but you can simply put it in a script or alias.

Comment: I will verify later it but I think that this file is generated on the first run of Midnight commander.